# Apache spark on cluster of only 2 computers

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing

I have 2 computers and I want to create a spark cluster with them. Since one of the computers should be master and one should be slave is it equal to only one computer in terms of speed? Can I set one of them as slave and master and the other as slave only? Can these 2 computers be windows and linux systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely! On the spark terminology, you can set up one of them to run your driver program as well as being a work node while the other one runs a work node only.

Regarding the OS, Spark tends to work really well on Linux both as development and deployable system. For Windows, I would recommend using it as development environment only.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use master node  also as a slave 
i.e  in you case you have 2 nodes And 1 master node and 2 slave node

you can use one Linux and one Windows system

you can follow below link for installation
https://medium.com/ymedialabs-innovation/apache-spark-on-a-multi-node-cluster-b75967c8cb2b

for Windows machine
https://hernandezpaul.wordpress.com/2016/01/24/apache-spark-installation-on-windows-10/